# jQuery DatePicker on Table Cell with html5 content editable attribute without input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I have a dynamic table that is generated by `PHP`. The cells of the table are editable using `contenteditable` `attr` of `html5`.

I have initialised the `jquery datepicker` like this.

```
$("table").find("tr").each(function() {
    $(this).find("td.date-selector").datepicker(
        { 
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
        }
    );
});
```

So that worked pretty well as it added `id` to my cells, and generated `html` is like this.

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Post_Name</th>
      <th>Post_Expectations</th>
      <th>Last_Date</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Queue</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable="true">Marketing Manager</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td contenteditable="true" class="date-selector" id="dp1459690831245">2016-02-14</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">Coimbatore</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">0</td>
      <td>
        <span class="table-remove-careers glyphicon glyphicon-remove table-remove-id"></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="table-up-careers glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up table-up-id"></span>
        <span class="table-down-careers glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down table-down-id"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable="true">Server Admin</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td contenteditable="true" class="date-selector" id="dp1459690831246">2016-05-15</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">Chennai</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">1</td>
      <td>
        <span class="table-remove-careers glyphicon glyphicon-remove table-remove-id"></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="table-up-careers glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up table-up-id"></span>
        <span class="table-down-careers glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down table-down-id"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- This is our clonable table line -->
    <tr class="hide">
      <td contenteditable="true">Post Name</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">Post Expectations .. (200 words)</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">Location</td>
      <td contenteditable="true" class="date-selector" id="dp1459690831247">Last Date</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">0</td>
      <td>
        <span class="table-remove-careers glyphicon glyphicon-remove table-remove-id"></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="table-up-careers glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up table-up-id"></span>
        <span class="table-down-careers glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down table-down-id"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now when I click on the field where I initialised `datepicker`, it is not showing up. Doing a little research on web, it showed the **jQuery DatePicker** only works on input tags or button clicks. Is there someway that it can be shown on the `contenteditable` `td`?

I need this because, I am creating a json of all the `tr` and sending it to server. Using `input` tag inside `td` will spoil the `json`.

Comment: Check this answer : _http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123193/is-it-possible-to-use-contenteditable-with-jquery-datepicker_