# How to add datetimepicker to contenteditable

Tags: jquery

How can I add date and time picker in my content editable using jquery.

This is my `<td>`:

```
<td class='datepicker' class="dq1" data-id1="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["dq1"].'</td>
```

This is my script:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        $(this).parent().find("[contenteditable=true]").focus().html(dateText).blur();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
    inst.text(dateText);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.17/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.17/jquery.datetimepicker.css">

<div class="datetimepicker" contenteditable>click here</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but not working coz I am using contenteditable

Comment: Yes, @Aniket Sahrawat I try the update but not working

Comment: @ArnoldLagbas This works with your options `buttonImage`, `dateFormat`, etc too. Edit the above snippet and see. You must be doing it wrong.

Comment: Ok, Thank you @Aniket Sahrawat

Comment: Thank you @Aniket Sahrawat, the calendar does not show even though I copied the code and script.

Comment: @ArnoldLagbas Does it execute correctly in above snippet? Try running the above snippet on SO.

Comment: @ArnoldLagbas Just copy paste [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b0x0j0gw/1/), it must work now

Comment: Yes @Aniket Sahrawat it is working fine but when I apply in my page it is not working. I  Dont know what is the problem .

Comment: @Aniket Sahrawat, the problem with your solution is that the resulting text is "Wed Nov 07 2018 23:06:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Standard Time)" ...?? I just want the date back.  That, and if there is a date in the DIV already (page load) such as 04/01/2018, that date is not set in datepicker; instead it's set to current date. So, while your solution "works", it seems to fail on these two points.