# JQuery Datetimepicker with contenteditable

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, contenteditable, inline-editing

Hi i found a solution for my inline edit Problem in [this Posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48597363/how-to-add-datetimepicker-to-contenteditable)

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
    inst.text(dateText);
  }
});

<div class="datetimepicker" contenteditable>click here</div>
```

Problem is the dateformat, if i try to append format: (YYYY-mm-dd) the content doesn't change. The Output is always something like "Thu Mar 19 2020 20:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)"

How to format the output Date to another format?